# Streetnames and background in layer are very pixelated (wms/wmts)

Tags: qgis

I am pretty new to Qgis, so I don't know much yet. 
Anyways, I have a map open where you can see a background map + streetnames of 
a country. THe problem is that the streetnames and the water and everything is 
very low quality. 
You can't even read it.
Is there a way to make it higher quality ?

Comment: You mention "wms/wmts" in your title but neither in your question. Are you using either of them?

Comment: Yes I used a wmts and a wms for the background layer with streetnames etc. Both are very low quality. That is what I meant

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.